# Error when trying to extract RGB values from PNG Image [Python PIL]

Tags: python, image-processing, python-imaging-library, png

I'm trying to create a simple image processing program in Python and the program works fine with .jpg files. Unfortunately, I can't ever seem to make it work for .png files and I really can't understand why.

Here's my code for getting the image and extracting the individual RGB values of each pixel:

```
image1 = Image.open('fake4.png')
            
pixels1 = image1.load()
  
for i in range(image1.size[0]): #column
    for j in range(image1.size[1]): #row
        r, g, b = image1.getpixel((i, j))
        #perform some checks on individual RGB values
```

When I run the code, it works fine for jpeg images, but with .png images I always get one of two errors at the line `r, g, b = image1.getpixel((i, j))`.

These errors are either:

```
builtins.ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 3)
```

or

```
builtins.TypeError: cannot unpack non-iterable int object
```

Python Image Library is something I'm new to and so is image processing in general.

Any ideas why is issue is caused and how to resolve it?

Comment: Have you tried printing the output of `getpixel()`? Is it 3 values, like you expect?

Comment: I tried what you suggested so inside the nested loop, I put `print("Index ", i, ", ", j, ": ", image1.getpixel((i, j)))` instead. It seems that all this function returns are single values. Here's part of the output: 

`Index  0 ,  0 :  1
Index  0 ,  1 :  1
Index  0 ,  2 :  1
Index  0 ,  3 :  1
Index  0 ,  4 :  1
Index  0 ,  5 :  1
Index  0 ,  6 :  1
Index  0 ,  7 :  1`

Comment: So there's your answer. The image doesn't seem to be RGB, rather, it seems to be grayscale.

Comment: Oh, I see. That make sense. Could you give any suggestions for how to process greyscale images or convert them to rgb?

Comment: Nevermind, I got it. Thanks a lot!

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's been solved in the comments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Nicolas Gervais for helping me figure out that the image I was attempting to process was actually a greyscale image. Because of that the getpixel() function would only return one value.

As such, I solved the issue by converting the image to RGBA format and that did the trick:

Here's my code for the workaround:

```
initialImage = Image.open('fake4.png')
image1 = Image.new("RGBA", initialImage.size)
image1.paste(initialImage)
```

Not sure of this is the most efficient way to do it, but it does the trick.